# Is there a way to print an entire array and not just printing the contents of the array by iterating through them?

Tags: arrays, c, printf

In `C`, is there a way to print an entire array. For example print (in full) each row from a 2D array, NOT iterating through its contents and printing them independently? Below is an example of how I imagined the code would be:

```
int main() {
int Numbers[4][4] = {{5, 1, 1, 6},
                          {2, 2},
                          {3, 3, 3},
                          {4, 4, 4}};


for (int i=0; i<=3; i++){
    printf("%i \n", Numbers[i]);

}

return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be along the lines of:

```
{5, 1, 1, 6}
{2, 2}
{3, 3, 3}
{4, 4, 4}
```

However, when  run the code I get the following output

```
-414054224 
-414054208 
-414054192 
-414054176
```

Comment: `Numbers[i]` (for any valid `i`) is an *array*, and the format `%i` is to print a *single* `int` value. For the values being printed, the array will decay to a pointer to its first element. And it's this pointer that is printed (using the wrong format). If the compiler doesn't warn you about passing the wrong arguments to `printf` you need to enable more warnings. Also note that arrays have a *fixed* size, you declare the size to be `4` which means the arrays will have `4` elements.

Comment: In short: If you want to print an array, you must loop over the array and print each element separately.

Comment: Also the computer does not know that you only want to print only {2,2}. *This is a 4x4 array with 16 numbers in it*. The extra numbers are 0, they are still part of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do what you are asking.  You cannot do operations on whole arrays in C; you must iterate through and print each element separately. Array expressions in C lose their "array-ness" under most circumstances.

Comment: Are there any libraries that allow doing numerical operations on arrays?

Comment: @MahmoudGabr: yes, but I don't do numerical work, so I don't have any good examples.  Note that the libraries still have to iterate through the arrays.  Even standard calls like `memcpy` and `strcpy` have to iterate through the array (although they may do so in larger chunks than single elements).